# Issue using mailbox in FreeRTOS (ESP32)

Tags: esp32, freertos, esp-idf

Start with this code:

```
/* ESP IDF Components */
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/semphr.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"
#include "esp_log.h"


// Defs
#define OBS_TYPE_MAX      12
#define OBS_ARRAY_SIZE     5

typedef struct obsStruct
{
    float   *obsArray[OBS_TYPE_MAX];    // Array of pointers to obs arrays
    uint32_t obsEnable;                 // which obsArray pointers are in use
    uint32_t cntr;                      // how many obs in obs array
} obs_struct_t; 

static const obs_struct_t OBS_INIT = {
    .obsArray = {0},
    .obsEnable = 0,
    .cntr = 0
}; 

// Functions
static esp_err_t mailbox_init() {
    esp_err_t ret = ESP_OK;

    // init mailbox
    // mailbox_obs = xQueueCreateStatic(1, sizeof(obs_struct_t), ucMailboxStorageArea, &xStaticQueue); // dyn
    mailbox_obs = xQueueCreate( 1, sizeof( obs_struct_t ) );
    configASSERT(mailbox_obs);
    ret = xQueueOverwrite(mailbox_obs, &OBS_INIT);
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"ret = %d (line num %d)", ret, __LINE__);
    // initialise Spinlock for critical sections
    spinlock_initialize(&mailboxSpinlock);

    return ret;
}

static esp_err_t register_obs(obs_t obsType, float obs[]) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"Add Obs[%d] to Mailbox.", obsType);
    esp_err_t ret = ESP_OK;

    // Critical Section!
    // taskENTER_CRITICAL(&mailboxSpinlock);  // Can't use when logging!
    
        // Read
        obs_struct_t temp = OBS_INIT;
        ret = xQueuePeek(mailbox_obs, &temp, 0);
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,"before temp.obsEnable = %lu", temp.obsEnable);

        // modify
        temp.obsEnable |= (uint32_t) 1 << obsType;
        temp.obsArray[obsType] = obs;

        // write
        ret = xQueueOverwrite(mailbox_obs, &temp);
        
    // taskEXIT_CRITICAL(&mailboxSpinlock);

    // debug stuff
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"after temp.obsEnable = %lu", temp.obsEnable);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "array[%d][%d] address = %02f", obsType, i, temp.obsArray[obsType][i]);
    }
    return ret;
}

// main
void app_main(void) {
    ret = mailbox_init();
    static float array1[5] = {0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1};
    static float array2[5] = {0.2, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2};
    ret = register_obs(0, array1);
    ret = register_obs(1, array2);
}
```

### Expected Outcome:

This is a tiny horrible minimum reproducible example. What I expect to see is the static struct getting filled up with after each call of register obs. After 2 calls, obsEnable should be equal to 3 ( 0x0000_0001 | 0x0000_0010 ).

### What actually happens:

Doesn't appear that the queue is holding on to it's values... The actual console log looks like this:

```
I (868) monkey_config.c: Initialise Mailbox. Product Code = 'S900001'
I (868) monkey_config.c: ret = 1 (line num 63)
I (878) monkey_config.c: Add Obs[0] to Mailbox.
I (878) monkey_config.c: ret = 1 (line num 91)
I (888) monkey_config.c: before temp.obsEnable = 0
I (888) monkey_config.c: after temp.obsEnable = 1
I (898) monkey_config.c: array[0][0] address = 0.100000
I (898) monkey_config.c: array[0][1] address = 1.100000
I (908) monkey_config.c: array[0][2] address = 2.100000
I (918) monkey_config.c: array[0][3] address = 3.100000
I (918) monkey_config.c: array[0][4] address = 4.100000
I (928) monkey_config.c: Add Obs[1] to Mailbox.
I (928) monkey_config.c: ret = 1 (line num 91)
I (938) monkey_config.c: before temp.obsEnable = 0
I (938) monkey_config.c: after temp.obsEnable = 2
I (948) monkey_config.c: array[1][0] address = 0.200000
I (948) monkey_config.c: array[1][1] address = 1.200000
I (958) monkey_config.c: array[1][2] address = 2.200000
I (968) monkey_config.c: array[1][3] address = 3.200000
I (968) monkey_config.c: array[1][4] address = 4.200000
I (978) monkey_config.c: Getting Mailbox for obs[0]
I (978) monkey_config.c: ret = 1 (line num 136)
I (988) monkey_config.c: before temp.obsEnable = 0
I (988) monkey_config.c: Getting Mailbox for obs[1]
I (998) monkey_config.c: ret = 1 (line num 136)
I (998) monkey_config.c: before temp.obsEnable = 0
I (1008) monkey_config.c: Barrel Shift Mailbox & incr Counter
I (1018) monkey_config.c: temp.obsEnable = 0
```

As you can see, the value of obsEnable is fine in the temp struct. But after writing and reading back in next function call, it is back to 0... I'm a bit puzzled by this. I would have thought a static queue would be safe as houses in this respect.

Have tried with dynamic & static - no change.
Have tried with critical code sections - no change.